# Custom UIActionSheet with UIDatePicker gives error "invalid context 0x0"

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to display a UIDatePicker in an iPad/iPhone application and I'm using a UIActionSheet with a UIDatePicker embedded within. When I'm testing the app with iOS 7 Simulator I'm getting the following error:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

I get the same error for `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor`, `CGContextSaveGState`, `CGContextSetFlatness` and a bunch of other similar `CGContext___` types.

What is strange is that I'm not getting this error when testing in iOS 6.1 Simulator.

I'm still new to iOS development so I'm wondering if modifying a UIActionSheet with custom views is something that Apple strongly advises against. If yes what other options do I have to display a UIDatePicker in a modal manner?

**Update**

As mentioned below, I've found an explanation for the error in Apple's documentation for UIActionSheet; it's pretty clearly explained the UIActionSheet **is not** to be subclassed and used to display subviews.

Comment: Reading the Apple's UIKit developer documentation for UIActionSheet I've found the following paragraph: _Subclassing Notes
UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to
present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own
and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:._ This explains the error message, and it means this subclassing misuse is enforced in iOS 7.